# What special symmetries is this subset of diffeomorphisms?

Tags: diffeomorphism-invariance

To make a general diffeomorphism I can make an infinitessimal transformation to the coordiante $x^\mu$ to $x^\mu + \delta f^\mu(x)$.

Now I want to restrict it so I only allow transformations such that:

$$\partial_\mu f^\nu(x) + \partial_\nu f^\mu(x) = 0$$

This is because a certain identity I was working on only works if this is the case. (To do with a transformation of the vierbein).

I have checked that all Lorentz symmetries, scale symmetries and special conformal symmetries respect this condition. Do you know if this condition has a name? I have a hunch that this might be the set of general conformal (angle preserving) symmetries or something similar. But I think that has a more complicated expression.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): The condition in its current form (v1) has inconsistent index positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition defines Killing vectors of the Minkowski metric. To see this, note that for an arbitrary metric, the action of a diff. $x^\mu\rightarrow x^\mu+\xi^\mu(x)$ on the metric is
$$
\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\mu\nu}=\nabla_\mu\xi_\nu+\nabla_\nu\xi_\nu,
$$
which incidentally is also where the Killing equation comes from.

For the Minkowski metric, of course the Christoffel symbols vanish so the vanishing of the Lie derivative is going to look like $\partial_\mu\xi_\nu+\partial_\nu\xi_\mu=0$.

Since you mention you are working in a Vierbein formulation, this should not be surprising at all. In such a formulation we have a local $SO(3,1)$ symmetry corresponding precisely to those transformations which leave the Minkowski metric invariant, and hence will also leave the metric computed from the Vierbeins invariant, which is to be expected from a frame field formulation of any field theory.

Comment: Thanks, it's all becoming clearer now. :)